# How to draw a parse tree when a small python file is parsed?

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

My objective is to understand how Abstract syntax tree works. I am able to parse a file using AST but i am not able to imagine how the parse tree would be constructed.I would like to explain with an scenario:

```
#A.py

class Parse_tree :
   def move():
      print "hello"

#parse.py

import ast

with open('A.py') as f:
   tree = ast.parse(f.read())
```

So the "A.py" file is parsed as an ast in "Parse.py". I want to know how the following example is transformed into a tree. How is the tree constructed ?

Comment: Generally by procedural attachments to parsing actions (usually reductions), which construct trees by building a node representing the reduce-to nonterminal and attaching previously constructed subtrees produced by the same process.  I doubt that answer helps you much; I suspect you don't know much about how parsing works.  Without that background, the answer can't make much sense.